# Question about ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, irreducible-polynomials, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I believe the following is a true statement, but I am unsure, so I wanted to check with people.

> If $p$ is an irreducible polynomial in $n$ indeterminates then $(p)$, the ideal generated by it, is prime.

My idea is:  Let $gh \in (p)$ this implies that $f$ divides $g$ or $h$.  Thus one of them is in $(p)$, the problem is that I never used the irreducible part.

Comment: It seems to me you need to show that $p$ irreducible implies $(p)$ is prime; that's probably the hard part!  Best of luck with it!  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the fact that the ring of polynomials in $n$ indeterminates (over a field) is a unique factorization domain (you find the proof in every starter's textbook on ring theory).

If $p$ divides $gh$, then $gh=pq$, so, by unique factorization, $p$ must be among the irreducible factors of $g$ or of $h$ (up to multiplications by nonzero constants).

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $f$ divides either $g$ or $h$ uses that $f$ is irreducible. Otherwise its irreducible components might be distributed amongst $g$ and $h$.